# commit ALL changes from working copy (synchronise repository with local content)

Tags: svn

I have directory Foo with some content: it changed a lot (something was removed, added, changed etc.). I would like to commit ALL these changes at once (or at as least steps as it's possible). I don't want to look for new/deleted elements (what disappeared should be removed, what is new should be added, what changed should be just commited). In case of conflict the local version should be taken. I don't care about moves/renames: I can accept delete+add sequence. In other words I want to fully synchronise my repository with my local content. Is it possible in some simple way?

Comment: If `Foo` is a working copy, just commit?

Comment: @crashmstr - no, adding and deleting are not reflected in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Foo` is not WC of repository, make it Working Copy

Before each commit, perform `svn status` and process all `!` and `?` statuses (`?` in assumption, that all not-needed in repo files already ignored)

```
>svn st
M       2.txt
!       Sub\1.txt
?       Sub\3.txt
M       Sub2\2.txt
```

All `!` must be `svn del $2`, all `?` have to be `svn add $2`

Commit+update (in order to have clean WC instead of mixed)

**PS:** Ordinary backup (and FAM-module) seems more natural solution in your case, than VCS

**Note for @crashmstr**

Plain commit will not play nicely: commit without del|add for WC in sample with status will produce

```
>svn commit -m "Changes 2"
Sending        2.txt
Sending        Sub2\2.txt
Transmitting file data ..
Committed revision 4.
```

i.e `Sub\1.txt` and `Sub\3.txt` will be skipped

Comment: Heh, I forgot about add/remove needed (been using git with staging "all" :)